ArcGIS Pro calculate sum of different feature class fields
I'm trying to calculate solar power production of one region using ArcGIS Pro. I calculated each building's power and I have 31 feature classes that have "Usable_Sr_kWh" field (Total production of electricity in a day). But I want to calculate each building's electricity production in a month and I want to use "Usable_Sr_kWh" values. How can I sum all the fields from different feature classes and gain month information.
Here is how my attribute tables look:


That worked thank you so much.

@Hornbydd since you gave the solution you should perhaps convert it to an answers so "Hellowhel" to mark it as the chosen solution .

An approach is to use the Merge tool to combine all the feature classes into a single feature class, then run that through the summary statistics tool summing your kWh field and using the building ID as the case field.
